# What is the difference between single and double modulus signs. Do they both mean magnitude?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, vector-analysis

What's the difference between a set of single modulus and a set of double modulus signs?

On textbooks I have seen the magnitude of two vectors vector as $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|$
but I've seen other sites where they've presented it as $\|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|$. Also, for derivatives does $|c'(x)| = \|c'(x)\|$?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not totally standardized.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between one or two lines depicting the norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486271/is-there-a-difference-between-one-or-two-lines-depicting-the-norm)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what notation the author has decided to use, but $| \cdot |$ is usually reserved for the absolute value of a real number, or the modulus of a complex number, whereas $\| \cdot\|$ is reserved for the norm of a vector.

Comment: And the $\|\cdot\|$ is always (that I have seen) read "norm", and often given a subscript if this is ambiguous, such as $\|x\|_2$. The $|\cdot|$ notation is often read in other ways, though the meaning is the same as if $\|\cdot\|$ were used, in the given context.