# What is the use of the double modulus signs?

Tags: notation, vectors

So far as I can tell, the author uses $\|\cdot\|$ to mean the magnitude of a vector, but I have only seen the notation $|\cdot|$ to mean the magnitude of a vector. Is there any difference? If so, what? And if not, why bother?

Comment: Notice this code: \|\cdot\|.  The difference between ||a|| and \|a\| is perhaps most conspicuous when you see the difference in rendering between ||a||||b|| and \|a\|\|b\|, thus: $||a||||b||$ versus $\|a\|\|b\|$. I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/875489/39599

Comment: In some circles, $|\cdot|$ denotes the Euclidean norm and $\|\cdot\|$ can denote any norm.  This is not an extremely widespread convention, though.

Comment: It can help aid in distinguishing vectors from scalars, and norms from absolute values.

Answer (score 23):

The reason some authors choose to use $\| \cdot \|$ notation instead of $| \cdot |$ is to better distinguish between vectors and scalars.

For example, writing the identity $|kv|=|k||v|$ is somewhat ambiguous whereas $\|kv\| = |k|\|v\|$ is not.

Comment: Of course, vectors are often distinguished some other way, e.g. $|k\mathbf{v}| = |k| |\mathbf{v}|$ or $|k\vec v| = |k| |\vec v|$.

Comment: It's also useful to distinguish the two in, for example, $L^p$ spaces, where $|f|$ denotes the function $|f|(x) = |f(x)|$ and $||f||$ denotes the $L^p$-norm of $f$.

Answer (score 5):

That's a common symbol for a norm in mathematics. I guess in your case it means the length of the vector.

For more information about norms in general, see *[Normed vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space)* (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2):

In regular vectors, they're generally equivalent. (note: "regular" here isn't a special subset of vectors, it's referring to the common meaning of "vector")

However, there are vector spaces that aren't just a list of numbers in the way that regular vectors are. And in some of these vector spaces, the absolute value of something can be more vague.

For example, consider the vector space for functions that consists of cosine and sine functions. From this, we have
$$
\|\sin(x)\| = 1
$$
as $\sin(x)$ is a unit function in the space (due to normalisation). However, $|\sin(x)|$ represents an always-positive function, not the norm of the function.

When treating vector spaces formally, retaining the distinction is of value. When simply working with regular vectors, there's no special need, and it's the author's choice.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are telling means a norm. So what is a norm, A norm is basically a function on a given vector space $V$ over the field $F$ of complex numbers. So a norm on $V$ is a function $p:V\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ having the following properties:

1) $p(av)=|a|p(v)$

2) $p(u+v)\leq p(u)+p(v)$

3) If $p(v)=0$ $\iff$ $v$ is the zero vector.

Where $a \in F $ and $v,u \in V $

You can find other properties and other uses of norm here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Its been a while since I've done analysis so correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't your 3rd property an "if and only if"?

Comment: Oh ya sorry for that @Hbeel

Comment: Done and thanks for that @HBeel